# My Submissions view filter incorrect

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, view, content-approval

On my SharePoint 2013 server I am researching content approval on a document library.
I created a document library and enabled approval and versioning (major and minor).

I also enabled the setting that everyone who can read, can also see concepts. Using the option where only reviewers can see concept-items, the above described behavior is still the same for reviewers.

Two views are automatically created:
my-sub.aspx and mod-view.aspx

I expected that the my-sub.aspx would filter like it suggests "My submissions". 
It looks like there is no filter at all, but only grouping on moderation status.
Also there is no "submitted by" field or such.

I know there are work-arounds (build a workflow for instance), but my questions are:

1. Does anyone has the same results
2. Is there anyone that uses this functionality in production and what do you tell to your users about the "My submissions".

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the same behaviour with My Submissions - looks weird and also curious if this is the default behaviour or if we're doing something wrong.  In any case, I modified the view by adding a Filter on **Created By**  is equal to **[Me]** and got the behaviour the users expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, my work-around is a person field that users have to fill in. Created By is not always equal to the one who submitted the file in my case. 
I upvoted cause it could be a potential work-around.